# Illustrator: Artboard X and Y?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

What are the X and Y settings of the Illustrator artboards good for?
Are they in any way relevant for print?

Answer (score 6):

Artboards represent the regions that can contain printable artwork. You can resize and set the orientation for your artwork by choosing settings in the Artboard, artboard is bounded by solid lines and represents the maximum printable area.

**X and Y Position Specifies the position of the artboard according to Illustrator’s workspace rulers.**

**we can use artboards for crop areas for printing or placement purposes,it crops the document according to settings of x and y in artboard**

Answer (score -3):

X and Y position Specifies the position of the artboard according to the rules of the Illustrator workspace.

Comment: This is answer is a copy-paste from the one below. Answers should be your original work or at least provide references.